# javascript for loop, get all items or 5

Tags: javascript

I am looking whether there is an easier way to achieve the following:

```
     var filesCount = files.length;

     for (var j = 0; j < filesCount; j++) {
                if (j < 5) {
                    vm.groupFiles.push({
                        "fileName": fileName,
                        "fileType": fileType,
                        "lastModifiedTime": lastModifiedTime,
                        "isContainer": isContainer,
                        "serverRedirectedUrl": serverRedirectedUrl,
                        "cleanTitle": cleanTitle,
                        "extention": extention
                    });
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I tried the following method but with no avail, and that made me doubt whether it is possible at all to do it in a shorthand method without polluting my for loop.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < (filesCount || 4); i++) {
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most important part of this question is understanding why

```
for (var i = 0; i < (filesCount || 4); i++) {
}
```

doesn't work.  I can only guess that you know `||` means "or" and are trying to apply English rules to how the word "or" can be used.  JavaScript, and all programming languages, have much more strict meanings for each "word" or symbol.  `||` is an operator; with its operands (the expressions to its left and right) it forms a new expression that evaluates to some value.

In this case, the expression on teh left is `filesCount`, and the expression on the right is `4`.  With most languages that trace their roots to `C` (JavaScript among them), the following are true:

- a numeric value of 0 is "false"
- a numeric value that is not 0 is "true"
- the expression `a || b` will return a "false" value of both `a` and `b` are "false" values, and will return a "true" value otherwise

Since `4` is a true value, `(filecount || 4)` must always be a true value.  The rules for *which* true value it returns vary by language and should never be relied upon anyway (for readability reasons); but as it happens in JavaScript you'll get the first operand (in left-to-right order) whose value is "true".  So if `fileCount` is non-zero, your code is the same as

```
for (var i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
}
```

The only time your code behaves differently is when `fileCount` is 0 (or some other false value, like null); in which case it behaves like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
}
```

So we need to think in terms of expressions.  And what you need is an expression that evaluates to `fileCount` unless `fileCount` is greater than 5, in which case it evaluates to 5.  (I'm going by your first code block when I say that; for some reason you switched to 4 in the second snippet.)

There are a number of ways to get that expression.  Most involve a calculation, so it can be a good idea to do the calculation once before starting the loop instead of putting the expression directly in the `for` statement.  (This is debatable in modern programming.  The original reason to do it was to avoid wasting calculations, but hand-optimizing is almost always a mistake anymore.  You should do what reads easiest or works best with the rest of your code.)

Anyway, one solution is

```
var n = Math.min(fileCount, 5);
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
}
```

Comment: Nice and helpful! Actually, the K&R `for` loop as such is "debatable in modern programming", JS seems to be the only scripting language that supports it.

Answer (score 5):

You could take the min value of count and 5 as length.

```
for (var j = 0, l = Math.min(files.length, 5); j < l; j++) {

}
```

Comment: **Also:** `for (var j = 0; j < filesCount && j < 5; j++) {}`

Comment: @Ele, if you have already a count/length variable, it is easier to shape the length than to use two conditions.

Comment: yes, it makes sense.  I always thinking to avoid further variables.  Btw +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with the shorthand if/ else operator:

```
var n = filesCount > 0 && filesCount < 5 ? filesCount : 5;

for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) { }
```